# Why does Orion's Jettison Motor, have four nozzles but eight Attitude Control Motors arranged in an octagon?

Tags: engines, orion-spacecraft, attitude-determination-and-control

Spaceflight 101's [Orion Spacecraft Overview](http://spaceflight101.com/spacecraft/orion/) shows the following tests for the escape system.

Why are there eight ACS thrusters arranged octagonally? Is it just to reduce cosine losses or does this allow for better, or perhaps easier control?

[image: Orion ACS thrusters]

[image: Orion's Jettison Motor]

---

**Update:** I've just seen something similar, with a four and eight configuration of pulsed thrust for very rapid response. This is a screen shot of a video about India's Shakti ASAT kill vehicle.

[image]

Hat tip to @Ohsin for [recommending](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35114/what-did-indias-recently-tested-asat-vehicle-really-look-like?noredirect=1#comment110866_35114) this interesting video about the rocket, and the test itself: [Official video on Mission Shakti (Project XSV1)](https://youtu.be/1-J4jVlx5Do)

[image: India Shakti ASAT Kill Vehicle]

Comment: Huh.  Do they use anything for roll control?  Or do they just use the symmetry and mass of the capsule/LAS assembly to justify not having it?

Comment: Interesting, now I have the same question about Apollo. I know one of the early Little Joe tests had a huge roll rate, I wonder if anything slowed it down after sep.

Comment: @Tristan I've spotted something similar and added an update.