# What did India's recently tested ASAT vehicle really look like?

Tags: military, weapon, india

Following up to [India just shot down a satellite from the ground. At what altitude range is the resulting debris field?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35093/12102) which shows the first image below (also seen in video) I also found the second image which looks like it has more stages.

Is either one of these known to be the ASAT tested by India on 27-Mar-2019 that blew up an Indian-owned satellite at circa 260 to 280 km?

YouTube: [DRDO's Anti Satellite (A-SAT) Test Visuals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODg0yNcTgUg)

From Times of India's [Watch: Launch of anti-satellite missile for Mission Shakti](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/watch-launch-of-anti-satellite-missile-for-mission-shakti/articleshow/68601492.cms):

[image: India ASAT?]

From [India's surprise ASAT test of 27 March 2019](https://sattrackcam.blogspot.com/2019/03/indias-surprise-asat-test-of-27-march.html):

[image: India ASAT?]

[image: India ASAT?]

Comment: Some close-up views of "Kill Vehicle" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-J4jVlx5Do

Comment: @Ohsin thank you! I've now linked to that in several places. Here's another "kill vehicle" video [Does the way this experimental kill vehicle moves and thrusts suggest it contains inertia wheels?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18790/12102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second image is ISRO's [Polar Satellite Launch Vehicle](https://www.isro.gov.in/launchers/pslv) which launched, among other payloads, Microsat-R (2019-006A) on Jan 24 2019, the probable target of the March 2019 ASAT test.

The first image and related footage does, according to many official sources (eg. [Air Force](https://twitter.com/IAF_MCC/status/1111094964849500160)), show the ASAT missile.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementary to @Jack's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35123/12102).

Hat tip to @Ohsin for [recommending](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35114/what-did-indias-recently-tested-asat-vehicle-really-look-like?noredirect=1#comment110866_35114) this interesting video about the rocket, and the test itself:

[image: India Shakti ASAT missile test 2019]

[image: India Shakti ASAT missile test 2019]

[image: India Shakti ASAT missile test 2019]

[image: India Shakti ASAT missile test 2019]

[image: India Shakti ASAT missile test 2019]

Last image seen by the kill vehicle, at ~10,400 m/s.

> The heat shield was ejected subsequently, and the IIR seeker locked on to the target at the expected range. The terminal guidance executed the small and precise corrections to the part of the kill vehicle, and the target was hit at the intended aim point, within 10 cm accuracy.
>
> The intercept occurred at a 283 kilometer height, in a hit-to-kill mode.
>
> The radars, and electro-optical systems captured the interception, and the on-board IIR seeker’s last image also confirms the same.

[image: India Shakti ASAT missile test 2019]